# Find Symbol in File

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I believe earlier versions (2010 and earlier) had a Find Symbol tab in the Find and Replace window. This doesn't appear to be the case in VS2013. My use case is as follows:

Source file open (C#), in a solution with a great many projects and cross-project references. Within a single source file, there is a "using XXX.YYY.ZZZ" reference at the header of the file. I would like to find all uses of symbols in the XXX.YYY.ZZZ namespace within the current file.

Comment: Do what I do - remove the reference and build the project. The errors will show you where it had been used.

Comment: @AdamV -- that's very close to what I've been doing. For my use case, remove the "using XXX.YYY.ZZZ" and follow the errors in the file that arise. I can't help but think that there should be a better way since that's clearly a hack.

Answer (score 0):

Edit->Find and Replace->Quick Find

or

right-click on XXX.YYY.ZZZ and choose 'Find all references'

Comment: Aye I already know the "Find all references" - however that's solution wide, and doesn't find the symbols below XXX.YYY.ZZZ -- the only references it finds in the file are the using XXX.YYY.ZZZ directive, not the classes below:

For example if in the same file I had
`var x = new Foo();`
Where Foo is XXX.YYY.ZZZ.Foo resolved via the previously mentioned step, Find all references will **NOT** find that line.

Comment: @eddyfice: Then delete the using statement or comment it and let the IDE or compiler tell you where it's used.

Comment: See my comment on the original Q - that's what I do now, it just seems like a hack :P